# using RTTI to recursively iterate inner records in delphi

Tags: delphi, rtti

I have a number of record structures in Delphi (Berlin) which I am trying to recursively iterate through using RTTI. The code is not working for inner records. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 Procedure WriteFields(Const RType  : TRttiType;
                       Const Test   : TTestRecord;
                       Var   Offset : integer);
 var
   RFields : TArray<TRTTIField>;
   i : integer;
   Val : TValue;
 begin
   RFields := GetFields(Rtype);
   try
     for i := Low(RFields) to High(RFields) do
     begin
       if RFields[i].FieldType.TypeKind <> tkRecord then
       begin
         Val := rfields[i].GetValue(@Test);
         writeln(Format('Field Name: %s, Type: %s, Value: %s, Offset: %d',[
                RFields[i].Name,
                RFields[i].FieldType.ToString,
                Val.ToString,
                RFields[i].Offset]));
       end
       else
       begin
         WriteLn(Format('------- Inner record : %s',[RFields[i].name]));
         //recursively call this routine for the other records, and fields
         Writefields(RFields[i].FieldType,Test,Offset);
       end;
       Offset := OffSet +  RFields[i].Offset;
     end;
  finally
    SetLength(RFIelds,0);
  end;
end;
```

Here is my test record structure

```
TInfo = packed record
  Age : integer;
end;

TTestRecord = packed record
  Name : String;
  Text : String;
  Info : TInfo;   //inner record structure
end;
```

Here's my test record data

```
  //set a few values on it
  Test.Name := 'Fred';
  Test.text := 'Some random text';
  Test.Info.Age := 50;
```

Here's the output of the code running in a console app

```
Size of 12

Field Name: Name, Type: string, Value: Fred, Offset: 0
Field Name: Text, Type: string, Value: Some text, Offset: 4
     ------- Inner record : Info
     Field Name: Age, Type: Integer, Value: 38642604, Offset: 0

Total offset of bytes read 12
```

As you can see, the value returned for the inner record Age, is garbage.

Comment: You're always passing `Test` in this call `rfields[i].GetValue(@Test)`. It should be address of the field of that inner record.

Comment: Totally agree with your deleted question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You are not passing the inner record instance to `WriteFields()` during the recursive call.**  You are passing the outer record instance again.  Thus, the call to `TRttiField.GetValue()` fails with undefined behavior, since you are giving it the wrong pointer.

If you change the 2nd input parameter to be a `Pointer` (which is what `TRttiField.GetValue()` expects anyway) or an untyped `const`, then apply `RFields[i].Offset` to that value when making recursive calls, your code will then work as expected.

For example:

```
Procedure WriteFields(const RType : TRttiType;
                      const Instance : Pointer);
var
  RField : TRTTIField;
  Val : TValue;
begin
  for RField in RType.GetFields do
  begin
    if RField.FieldType.TypeKind <> tkRecord then
    begin
      Val := RField.GetValue(Instance);
      WriteLn(Format('Field Name: %s, Type: %s, Value: %s, Offset: %d',[
              RField.Name,
              RField.FieldType.ToString,
              Val.ToString,
              RField.Offset]));
    end
    else
    begin
      WriteLn(Format('------- Inner record : %s, Offset: %d',[RField.Name, RField.Offset]));
      //recursively call this routine for the other records, and fields
      WriteFields(RField.FieldType, PByte(Instance)+RField.Offset);
      WriteLn('-------'); 
    end;
  end;
end;

...

var
  Test: TTestRecord;
...
WriteFields(..., @Test);
```

Or:

```
Procedure WriteFields(const RType : TRttiType;
                      const Instance);
var
  RField : TRTTIField;
  Val : TValue;
begin
  for RField in RType.GetFields do
  begin
    if RField.FieldType.TypeKind <> tkRecord then
    begin
      Val := RField.GetValue(@Instance);
      WriteLn(Format('Field Name: %s, Type: %s, Value: %s, Offset: %d',[
              RField.Name,
              RField.FieldType.ToString,
              Val.ToString,
              RField.Offset]));
    end
    else
    begin
      WriteLn(Format('------- Inner record : %s, Offset: %d',[RField.Name, RField.Offset]));
      //recursively call this routine for the other records, and fields
      WriteFields(RField.FieldType, (PByte(@Instance)+RField.Offset)^);
      WriteLn('-------');
    end;
  end;
end;

...

var
  Test: TTestRecord;
  ...
WriteFields(..., Test);
```

In both cases, the output is what you are expecting:

```
Field Name: Name, Type: string, Value: Fred, Offset: 0
Field Name: Text, Type: string, Value: Some random text, Offset: 4
------- Inner record : Info, Offset: 8
Field Name: Age, Type: Integer, Value: 50, Offset: 0
-------
```