# Delphi packed records, how to iterate through fields

Tags: delphi, record, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have a Delphi packed record:

```
type
  PFileList = ^TFileList;
  TFileList = Packed Record
    ProfileName: string;
    ProfileDescription: string;
    ProfileMemo: string;
    CustomURL: string;
    SSOProperties: string;
  end;
type
  TArrOfFileList = array of TFileList;
```

I have a variable `FProfileModel` that is of type `TArrOfFileList`.

How do I iterate through the fields of `FProfileModel` without having to specify like `FProfileModel[0].ProfileName`, `FProfileModel[0].ProfileDescription`, etc.

The reason is that I would like to know the number of fields in `FProfileModel` so as to migrate to another type in the future.

I am using Delphi Sydney and Alexandria as development platform.

Edit:

I am using this code to save the record to file using UkDynamic:

```
    procedure SaveProfile(const fs: string; var array1: 
      TArrOfFileList);
    var
      Stream: TFileStream;
    begin
       Stream := TFileStream.Create( fs, fmCreate);
       try
         TKBDynamic.WriteTo(Stream, array1, 
           TypeInfo(TArrOfFileList));
       finally
         Stream.Free;
       end;
    end;
```

**Solution**

Thanks to the tip from @SilverWarior, I was able to further expand the use of UkDynamic to add versioning to the records saved on file.

Thank you all for helping out.

Comment: What Delphi version?

Comment: @KenWhite, thank you for responding. I am using the newest and the greatest, Alexandria 11

Comment: See also [using RTTI to recursively iterate inner records in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52087608/576719)

Comment: "*I would like to know the number of fields in `FProfileModel`*" - well, all of the fields of `TFileList` are the same type, so you could just use `SizeOf(TFileList) div Sizeof(string)` to get the field count. And then multiply that by `Length(FProfileModel)` if needed.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "fields"?  You're talking about the "fields in FProfileModel", but that's just an array - the record has fields, but the array does not.  Are you trying to iterate over the array or through the fields of each record in the array (without needing to know what they're called or how many they are or what type they are)?

Comment: @LURD, thank you for the resource link. Using that example in the link, should I be calling WriteFields(Test) where Test is TFileList(FProfileModel[0])?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do here?  Write the records to a file?  It would help to know your objective.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you for the information. The field count would help to at least identify that the record is different

Comment: @J..., thank you for responding and you're right. I am trying to iterate through the fields of each record in the array without needing to know what they're called or how many there are, although knowing what they're called would help to check

Comment: @J..., I did save the records to file using UkDynamic and loading them back again. But I would like to check if the saved files are of an older structure and plan a migration idea

Comment: So... at some point the record definition got changed and you now have files with two or more different record formats?

Comment: @J..., you're absolutely right

Comment: That rather complicates things, because the challenge will be to know the format of the record in the file before you read it in.  To read a record correctly from a file generally requires knowing its type precisely, but this is a record of strings, which normally won't save correctly as a record (it's just pointers).  Presumably UkDynamic does something to store records of this type, but **that's** the format you'll need to reverse engineer, it seems.  I've not used that library so I have no idea how it stores records of strings.

Comment: @JennyL in that situation, you probably should store version info in your files. In this case, since the file already exists, consider that v1. Add version info to your next file, and consider that v2. Then, from now on, when reading in a file, validate the version stored (or missing) to know what format to read in it as.  Of course, there are other ways to handle this, too.

Comment: @J..., you're absolutely right again. I would check at least for 1 format and if it does not match, then copy the data over to the new record type and save it back to file overwriting the old format file. The hurdle is trying to check for the format. I need to somehow iterate through the "fields" of the record and see if there is a difference. Or maybe find a field that does not exist, thus confirming that it is an old format

Comment: Your best bet is probably to retain the various historical definitions of the records in your source and you'll need to test each one when reading in an unknown file - then check which one worked.  You'd probably need to use UkDynamic to do that because it will have some type of custom format to handle records with strings. Going forward, as Remy noted, keeping version information in the file is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau, I like your idea of version. Would I create or look for a new field in the record called "Version"? How would I look for this field?

Comment: Write the version as the first entry of the file, or as part of a file header, then append everything else.  The records themselves don't need to duplicate the information.

Comment: @J..., I included the function in the edited question that I used to save the format to file. How would I add the version to this? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: @JennyL Well, that's now a separate question, which you should ask... in a separate question.

Comment: @JennyL you could have `SaveProfile()` write a hard-coded integer to the `TFileStream` to act as a signature, followed by a byte/integer for the version, before calling `TKBDynamic.WriteTo()`.  Then, when reading the file back in, check for that signature/version first. If not found, go back to Position 0 and assume the old format, otherwise read the remaining data after the version as a new format appropriate for the version being reported.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you for the great tip. I will definitely give it a try

Comment: I have just checked [Github page](https://github.com/KrystianBigaj/kblib) for `TKBDynamic` library and its seems ability to work with multiple versions is already implemented. I recommend you check the RecordVersions demo to see how this should be handled properly. By the way since you are not passing anything to `vcVersion` optional parameter of `WriteTo` function Default version of 1 is being used meaning that all your current data is stored as being version 1.

Comment: You can't look for fields in data stored to disk in some unknown format. You need to know something about the format. You need a protocol. Probably what you really want is to store this in JSON or some such format.

Comment: @SilverWarior, thank you very much for the info! I will dig into it

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes, I did explore JSON as a possible replacement